# HP-UFT object not found in object repository error

Tags: hp-uft

Getting the following error while executing script:

```
WebList object was not found in the Object Repository.
Check the Object Repository to confirm that the object exists or to find the correct name for the object.

Line (1221): "objParent.WebList(vstrObjectName).select vstrValue".
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please help us answer your question by providing more information: what script are you running? What results are you expecting. It helps to provide more of the code that has a bearing on the error. For helpful tips on asking questions, go to http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 2):

I understand, it shouldn't be as simple as the object isn't available in the repository but in in case- Try to use 'Locate in repository'

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Line (1221) is trying to access a WebList object by name, but the name is stored in a variable; it is not a string literal in the code.

There might be 3 different things going on here.

1) if you were attempting to use Descriptive Programming, then it sounds like the contents of vstrObjectName didn't include the ":=" symbol that would make QTP believe the string is a description...  So, QTP thinks the string stored in vstrObjectName must be the name of an object in the Object Repository.

I would like to guess that you were trying to use descriptive programming, since (based on the fact that the parent, and the parameter are also both contained in variables) it looks like you are avoiding using any string literals in that line.

2) If you were attempting to control an object with a name from the Object repository, then either the string contained in vstrObjectName didn't contain a valid object name (that belongs to objParent), or

3) the object refered to by objParent isn't the one you were expecting.

In any of these cases, if it were me, the first thing I would do is add a print statement before line 1221 as:
Print "vstrObjectName:'" & vstrObjectName & "'"
...and run it again.  That should show the string that you were referencing.  I would guess that the resulting output line is not what you expected.

Another thing to check is to make sure that the action or function that contains that line is executed from within an action that contains that named object in it's OR scope.  (i.e. open the action and hit CTRL-R, it shows the combined OR that is visible to that action).  If the line is in a function library, and it gets called from an action that doesn't have the object in it's local OR, or an attached shared OR, then you will get the same error.  This kind of problem is very easy to cause if you use multiple actions, and the action containing the call to the function that contains your line (line 1221) doesn't actually have that object available to it due to it's OR scope.

To answer the question you asked - how to add object into the OR - you could use several methods - recording, guispy's add to OR button, manually add from the OR screen, etc...    but in the end, you need that object in the OR to have a name that matches whatever is in vstrObjectName.

Answer (score 0):

Some potential examples where an object can be selected:

Dynamically change the object based on the name of the object in the object repository:(must exist in the repository)

```
Dim objectname
objectname = "SAP Work Manager"
msgbox  WpfWindow(objectname).Exist
```

Select an object that does not exist in the Object repository, by its properties:

```
WpfWindow("text:=SAPWorkManager").Exist
```

[Example page of UFT tips](https://www.joecolantonio.com/2010/08/12/quicktest-object-recognition/)